# Iterate over pandas row to check a large number of conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataframe which captures system data. I would like to iterate over the rows to check a large set of conditions (similar to decision tree).

For eg dataframe is:

```
          timestamp   v01   v02    v03    v04   
0  01/06/2020 00:00  99.9   99.9   99.9   99.9   
1  01/06/2020 00:05  89.9   99.9   99.9   99.9  
2  01/06/2020 00:10  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0  
.......
```

My large list of conditions (more than 50) is shown below. For each row in the dataframe, it must check against the 50 conditions.

```
0 'v01==100.0, v02==100.0, v04==100.0', 
1 'v01==100.0, v01==100.0, v04==100.0',  
2 'v01==100.0, v02==100.0, v03==100.0',  
.........
```

Algorithm:

1. row1 in dataframe check against "v01==100.0 & v02==100.0 & v04==100" followed by the next condition.
2. Go to next row in dataframe and check the conditions again.

Is there an efficient method for me iterate over each row in the dataframe and check all the conditions (ie 50 rows of condition)? I would also like to know the index of the conditions that is False.

So far, I think df.query() seems to be most efficient but I would not be able to tell which condition was not met.

Another method I can think of is to convert the following strings (eg 'v01==100.0, v02==100.0, v04==100.0') into df['v01']==100 ...  Is there a method to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a code-writing service, and you're expected to do at least a bit of research yourself before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
dataframe_name['Column_name'] == 'value'
```

This will give you series containing 'True' and 'False' value for each rows.